# What is the correct input to have the program print the sentence: Exactly! Good Job

Tags: c, output, logic

Read and understand the following code.

Provide the correct input to have the program print the sentence:
Exactly! Good Job.

Before submitting your answer, please check its correctness by executing the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <inttypes.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

static int64_t green_day[] = {68053, 56286, 93562, 32510, 80652, 62435};

const static int N = sizeof(green_day)/sizeof(*green_day);

static void fail(){

    puts("Nope!");

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}

static void pink_floyd(int64_t a, int64_t f, int64_t r){

    if ( a - r / 7 + 3 * f / 11 )

    fail();

}

static void ac_dc(int k, int64_t d){

    int64_t i = d;

    for(; k<N; ++k) {

        if ((k % 2) == 0)

        continue;

        i += green_day[k];

    }

    if (i != 152916)

    fail();

}

static void the_rolling_stones(int t, int64_t n){

    if (t<N) {

    if (t % 2)

    the_rolling_stones(++t, n);

    else the_rolling_stones(t + 1, n * green_day[t]);

    } else if (n != 769547450)

    fail();

}

int main(){

    int64_t h, x, v;

    printf("Please enter the right three numbers: ");

    fflush(stdout);

    if (scanf("%" SCNd64 " %" SCNd64 " %" SCNd64, &h, &x, &v) != 3)

    fail();

    green_day[0] = h;
    green_day[5] = x;
    green_day[4] = v;

    ac_dc(0, 61106);

    the_rolling_stones(1, 5);

    pink_floyd(h, x, v);

    puts("Exactly! Good job.");

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you work through any of the failure cases yourself?

Comment: What's the purpose of this code?

Comment: @Darth-CodeX just want to know the logic to find out different variables values of a function, if only one function is available.

Comment: @samyyy15 Yes, I got the answer. -587 3014 1645.

Answer (score 0):

First the answer:

```
Please enter the right three numbers: -587 3014 1645
Exactly! Good job.
```

If you can trace the call, each function gives out value of an unknown.

- `ac_dc()` gives you `x = 3014`
- `the_rolling_stones()` gives you `v = 1645`
- `pink_floyd()` gives you the last `h = -587`

Tracing calls is beyond the scope of this site. If the person who asked you this question doesn't follow it up with `Show me how you got it?` then the whole exercise was a moot point.

Comment: Thank you very much for the right answer. But still now the logic is not clear.

Comment: How you did it ? 

Answer (score 0):

-Please enter the right three numbers: -311 2112 1855
Exactly! Good job.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <inttypes.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    static int64_t aerosmith[] = { 37262, 52682, 47166, 68777, 97309, 53919 };
    const static int N = sizeof(aerosmith) /sizeof(*aerosmith);
    static void fail(){
            puts("Nope!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    static void guns_n_roses(int64_t e, int64_t p, int64_t n) {
            if ( e - n / 7 + 3 * p / 11)
                    fail();
    }
    static void metallica(int j, int64_t k) {
            int64_t g = k;
            for(; j<N; ++j) {
                    if ((j % 2) == 0)
                            continue;
                    g += aerosmith[j];
                }
                if (g != 181228)
                      fail();
    }
    static void the_beatles(int u, int64_t c ) {
            if (u<N) {
                    if (u % 2)
                            the_beatles(++u, c);
                        else the_beatles(u + 1, c * aerosmith[u]);
                    } else if (c != 262478790)
                            fail();
    }
    int main(){
           int64_t a, y, w;
           printf("Please enter the right three numbers: ");
           fflush(stdout);
           if (scanf("%" SCNd64 "%" SCNd64 "%" SCNd64, &a, &y, &w) != 3)
                fail();
           aerosmith[0] = a;
           aerosmith[5] = y;
           aerosmith[4] = w;
           metallica(0, 57657);
           the_beatles(1, 3);
           guns_n_roses(a, y, w);
           puts("Exactly! Good job. ");
    }
```

-I recommend that if you are faced with such a type of problem, try to trace each function separately,in the above example you can start tracing from a metallica function, display the values in each iteration.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static int64_t ac_dc[] = { 14479, 12574, 54786, 51996, 77903, 16499 };
const static int N = sizeof(ac_dc)/sizeof(*ac_dc);
static void fail(){
puts("Nope!");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
static void linkin_park(int64_t i, int64_t z, int64_t o){
if ( i - o / 7 + 3 * z / 11 )
fail();
}
static void the_beatles(int n, int64_t u){
int64_t s = u;
for(; n<N; ++n) {
if ((n % 2) == 0)
continue;
s += ac_dc[n];
}
if (s != 159276)
fail();
}
static void metallica(int y, int64_t d){
if (y<N) {
if (y % 2)
metallica(++y, d);
else metallica(y + 1, d * ac_dc[y]);
} else if (d != 197887032)
fail();
}
int main(){
int64_t r, l, h;
printf("Please enter the right three numbers: ");
fflush(stdout);
if (scanf("%" SCNd64 " %" SCNd64 " %" SCNd64, &r, &l, &h) != 3)
fail();
ac_dc[0] = r;
ac_dc[5] = l;
ac_dc[4] = h;
the_beatles(0, 92627);
metallica(1, 3);
linkin_park(r, l, h);
puts("Exactly! Good job.");
}
```

These functions give value of S & D, but what is the third value it will give while tracing the call of each function

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static int64_t ac_dc[] = { 14479, 12574, 54786, 51996, 77903, 16499 };
const static int N = sizeof(ac_dc)/sizeof(*ac_dc);
static void fail(){
 puts("Nope!");
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
static void linkin_park(int64_t i, int64_t z, int64_t o){
 if ( i - o / 7 + 3 * z / 11 )
 fail();
}
static void the_beatles(int n, int64_t u){
 int64_t s = u;
 for(; n<N; ++n) {
 if ((n % 2) == 0)
 continue;
 s += ac_dc[n];
 }
 if (s != 159276)
 fail();
}
static void metallica(int y, int64_t d){
 if (y<N) {
 if (y % 2)
 metallica(++y, d);
 else metallica(y + 1, d * ac_dc[y]);
 } else if (d != 197887032)
 fail();
}
int main(){
 int64_t r, l, h;
 printf("Please enter the right three numbers: ");
 fflush(stdout);
 if (scanf("%" SCNd64 " %" SCNd64 " %" SCNd64, &r, &l, &h) != 3)
 fail();
 ac_dc[0] = r;
 ac_dc[5] = l;
 ac_dc[4] = h;
 the_beatles(0, 92627);
 metallica(1, 3);
 linkin_park(r, l, h);
 puts("Exactly! Good job.");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).